# Determine if instance has settable property during runtime in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, introspection

I am porting old code to Swift. I wrote a custom input view, which works with certain custom views of mine. Here's the convenience method I use to attach the input view:

```
+ (POGramophoneView *)attachToView:(UIView *)view delegate:(id)delegate
{
    if ([view.inputView isKindOfClass:self]) return (POGramophoneView *)view.inputView;

    POGramophoneView *gramophone = [[POGramophoneView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 267)];

    gramophone.attachedView = view;

    NSAssert([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setInputView:)], @"Gramophone view %@ cannot attach to %@ because it does not respond to setInputView:", gramophone, view);

    // This line
    [view performSelector:@selector(setInputView:) withObject:gramophone];

    [view reloadInputViews];

    return gramophone;
}
```

Since `inputView` of `UIView` is readonly, I have to check if the view passed to me can have an input view set. I don't know how I should port the marked line to Swift. How do I check if the passed view has `inputView` declared as settable?

```
class func attachToView(view: UIView, delegate: POGramophoneViewDelegate) -> POGramophoneView {
    if view is POGramophoneView {
        return view
    }

    var gramophone = POGramophoneView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 267))
    gramophone.attachedView = view

    // set inputview to new gramophone
    view.reloadInputViews()

    return gramophone
}
```

Comment: NSAssert and performSelector is daft - you can just call the method. Method call has a built-in assert that the selector is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift does provide function to convert a string literal into *Selector* data type. You can write it like this

```
if view.respondsToSelector(Selector("setInputView:")) {
    // To call the selector use KVO technique.
    view.setValue(gramophone, forKey:"inputView");
}
```

Comment: That's okay, but how do I actually invoke the selector?

Comment: Nope, it won't. `UIView` doesn't declared `setInputView:`.

Comment: Oh, i see..., try using KVO like; _view.setValue(gramophone, forKey:"inputView"). It might not be the best way but i can't think of anything else unless you change your design and use Polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Add it to your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @duci9y I have updated the answer. You may accept now :)

Comment: Just an FYI, you can directly pass string literals where a `Selector` type is asked for. No need to convert.